# Get specific records from sql database when using aggregate function as Sum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using this query to filter some record from my sql database:

```
select Distinct x, SUM(y)AS Total 
from T  
where j=2 
group by x
```

The returned values are as follows:

```
2585   -1
1804   -8
1781   900.56
1712   -6
1612   -2
2591   66
```

Is there a way to filter the result `where Sum(y) > 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Having.Where clause acts  on individual records,Having acts on Groups

```
select Distinct x,
 SUM(y)AS Total from T  
where j=2 group by x
having sum(y)>0
```